# Is Kde plasma out of date on Debian?

Tags: debian, kde, distributions

Is Kde Plasma outdated on Debian 10 Buster? I noticed that the Kde on Debian felt like it had less features than on other Linux distributions do. Is this the case? I tried out Manjaro Kde and Kde neon and their flavors of Kde Plasma seemed to have more features.

Comment: Does Help > About tell you version number? If so maybe you could compare them

Answer (score 2):

Debian stable will always have older versions of packages, that's the stable part. If you want to have newer packages, you should use testing. (Note: Debian testing doesn't mean broken or dangerous, just that the new software can be sometimes buggy, it's normal and if you want rock stable software, you should use stable (that's usually important on servers). See [Choosing a Debian distribution](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/choosing.en.html) for more information).

Buster currently has Plasma 5.14, testing already has 5.19. You can check available versions for all Debian packages [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=plasma-desktop).

Comment: Technically, Debian stable doesn’t always have older versions of packages ;-). When it’s released, the packages are in many cases quite recent. But they don’t get upgraded over the life of the release. Note that the documentation you linked to recommends *unstable* over testing, in situations where stable isn’t appropriate (assuming the user has enough experience). In practice you really need both testing and unstable, and know when to use both...